# How can I automate "firebase deploy"?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is there any way I can automate my "firebase deploy" pushes to Firebase Hosting using a script?  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: This should be possible, since `firebase-tools` is a valid node module itself nowadays. But somehow I can't get it to work either. Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Sure.  I've tried calling 'firebase deploy' directly using PHP's shell_exec(), which didn't work.  I then made a bash script (using the command and token) and tried calling it via shell_exec(), which also didn't work.  The bash script ran via shell_exec(), and echo'ed out text I put in it, but the firebase command didn't run.  The bash script itself worked on the command line directly and ran the 'firebase deploy', however.  I'm thinking it might have something to do with it actually needing to be run from the command line -something to do with the user account present at the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple different approaches:

Firebase's own David East on how to do it with Travis and GitHub
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLVzozWDYAs

I took an alternate approach, since my automation tool is written in java.

- firebase CLI installed in the bash shell, previous to launching my java binary.
- [deploy.sh] shell script runs "firebase deploy" command.
- java binary has internal code to run the [deploy.sh] script.

Bottom line - no matter what your automation binary is written in, as long as it can shell out and run your [deploy.sh] script in the same shell that firebase is installed in, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and run this command to generate a new CI token. this will help a lot if you are deploying your project on **GitHub**

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase deploy --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

to complete the automation process

```
firebase login:ci
```

personal suggestion: [click here to see steps of using all commands](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/11/29/continuous-deployment-for-firebase-using-semaphore.html)